# How to get stack trace error exception in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'm getting following error with one of the third party library in which i have no access to the code. This error is intermittently being thrown and i have no idea what caused the error since i can't view the code. The library is in .SO extension which running in Linux and the library is compiled with C++ version 11 and i have exception catch routine in my function with e.what().

> An invalid memory reference (segmentation violation) has occurred.

Is there anyway i can view the stack trace for that error when it is being thrown? Also, any suggestion or advise on what is that error about?

Comment: Segmentation violation is nothing you can catch with a C++ exception. A process where a segmentation violation (i.e. access to an invalid memory address) occurs is considered as corrupted and aborted by the OS (for a reason). You can look into the call stack where your code calls a function of that 3rd party lib. and check whether there is something wrong. However, the access violation might result from an earlier call as well having left corrupted data in that lib.

Comment: Segment fault is an OS exception that cannot be handled in your program. To backtrace the stack, you need to use a debugger.

Comment: What kind of debugger i can use to backtrace the stack?